# is there relation between the turing machine halting prob & 3 CNF SAT?

Tags: algorithm

is there relation between the turing machine halting prob & 3 CNF SAT?
i can't find this any books of algorithm 
what is the relation between them?

Comment: They are different problems. Halting problem is about "the impossibility (non-existance) of a machine to decide whether a Turing Machine will stop on an input". 3 CNF SAT is about "the hardness of a class of problems (but still solvable), which cannot be solved (until now) in polynomial time"

Comment: i do think so. it's make no sense but my teacher said that if a turing machine is equivalent with computer program,there will be a relation between them and i have no idea about this issue T^T

Comment: So are you trying to find the relation between "Turing machine and 3CNF SAT" or "Halting problem and 3CNF SAT"?

Comment: Halting problem and 3CNF SAT

Comment: In that case, probably you will need to find out what does your teacher want you to understand. You can try asking this question to your teacher: "What kind of relation are you expecting? Because the two are different problem, halting problem is about undecidability, while 3CNF SAT is about NP-completeness."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about (very) theoretical computer science.

Answer (score 4):

The halting problem is harder.

3-SAT is NP-complete, while the halting problem is undecidable in the general case. In other words, it's impossible to make an algorithm to solve the general halting problem on a Turing machine.

An intuition for why is that the halting problem can be made as hard as any decision problem solvable on a Turing machine. You can write a solver for a difficult problem that halts if it finds the answer, then ask if that solver will halt.

Comment: "can be made as hard as any decision problem in existence" is a bit not helpful (if not incorrect), since the core conclusion from halting problem is the **non-existence** of a machine that can solve halting problem.

Comment: Good point, I'll rephrase.

Comment: "The halting problem is harder" is also quite ambiguous, as it actually **cannot** be solved. haha. It's like saying "Walking on the sun is harder than swimming in the south pole", which, if one does not know that it is impossible, will still try to make sense out of it.

Comment: The OP asked for what the relation is, and I take that to mean if they're in the same class or not. In that sense 'harder' answers that. I also do say that the *general case* is impossible. Note that HP can be solvable in special cases, so it's not completely accurate to say it's totally impossible. Then we can talk about non-Turing machines... But let's not lose sight of the forest for the trees.

Comment: "the halting problem can be made as hard as any decision problem in existence" is wrong in the sense that there are problems that cannot be reduced to the halting problem. For example, the problem whether two Turing machines compute the same function can't be reduced to the halting problem, while there is a reduction the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

The halting problem is about what languages can be recognized by Turing machines, even having infinite time. This is stricltly logical problem.

The 3SAT problem is about how many operations are needed to solve a problem, which means how much time do you need. This is a problem about finding fast algorithms, because slow algorithms are known to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The halting problem is impossible to solve on a Turing machine, while 3SAT solvable. What other kind of relations are you looking for?

Comment: i think so. it's make no sense but my teacher said that if a turing machine is equivalent with computer program,there will be a relation between them but i have no idea T^T